# Xamrin.Forms (PCL) WebView with Location (latitude and longitude)

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, location

I've used DependencyService to get a custom location class with long, lat, etc. This is the class:

```
public class CurrentLocation
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Altitude { get; set; }
    public float Accuracy { get; set; }
}
```

but I'm not understand how I can pass this values to any URL in a WebView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a `WebView`, you can set its `Source` property to a URL. For example in your content page's constructor,

```
var webview = new WebView() { Source = "http://example.com?lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng };
this.Content = webview;
```